# How to map Angular stacktrace to sourcemap in script?

Tags: angular, source-maps

I deployed an Angular app with production build. When an error occurs I log it so can I check that the next day. The log shows the error stack in the minified production build:

```
/main.*****.js:1:7466
```

As I have no chance to reproduce it in the browser so I cannot use the sourcemaps in the browser. I want to write a script where I can paste this error stack and it finds out where it occurs in the code.

Is this possible and yes, which is the correct approach?

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the same situation and I stumbled upon this npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sourcemapped-stacktrace

I wasn't able to try it out yet but it does seem very fitting.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.